# DropDownListFor with no item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

I have two `DropDownListFor`s. With changing the first one's selected item, the second one's list changes. There's no problem til here.

The problem is I want the second list to be empty before the first change of the first `DropDownListFor`. How can I do this?

In short, how can I have a `DropDownListFor` with no items at first?

Comment: Show your Code or show jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it. It was so simple. :)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Student,
    new List<SelectListItem>() {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "", Value = "" }
    })
```